# base Branch not displaying all the branches available on UI pull request

Tags: git, github

I am trying to merge my branch into another branch by creating a pull request using github UI, however when trying to select the base branch(branch where I want to merge) the branch I want to merge in is not displaying on the list.[image]

there is not much information I found about it.

the process to create the PR is using the console.
git add .
git commit -m "text"
git push

and after opening the link they provide to create the PR using the interface.

first time having this issue, it worked perfect the other times I tried the same process.

thanks to whatever info you can give in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

Whenever a branch is merged to master/main, it gets deleted by github by defaut(our configuration does it), in this case someone merged before me to master, it was enough with reopening again.